# VBA Count values based on font color

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need to add values of a range when its contents are of a certain font color (e.g., black). What I have is a a table where I am conditionally formatting the color of values. For e.g., if the "Status =Carry Over" then I am coloring the row Red. (see attachment).

Now, after the conditional formatting, I want to sum all the number values under a specific column that are **NOT** in red color.

I have a piece of vba code to add such values, but the problem is, the conditional coloring is throwing the code off. As long as I am manually coloring the rows, the code is ignoring the red rows. If I use the conditional coloring option, then even the colored rows are taken into account.

I am calling the below UDF using this formula =ConditionalColorSum(C2:C30)

```
Public Function ConditionalColorSum(rnge As Range) As Double
' Total only cells with red font numbers
    Application.Volatile
    Dim Total As Double, cl As Range
    Total = 0
        For Each cl In rnge.Cells
            If cl.Font.Color = vbRed Then    'Change 'vbRed' to the color you want
            Total = Total + cl.Value
            End If
        Next
    ConditionalColorSum = Total
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

The Conditional formatting formula looks like above:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.displayformat)

> Actions such as changing the conditional formatting or table style of a range can cause what is displayed in the current user interface to be inconsistent with the values in the corresponding properties of the Range object. Use the properties of the DisplayFormat object to return the values as they are displayed in the current user interface.

The only way to get the color due to conditional formatting is to use `DisplayFormat`

```
If cl.DisplayFormat.Font.Color = vbRed Then
```

But per [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat)

> Note that the DisplayFormat property does not work in user-defined functions.

So one cannot use UDF to count the colors directly from the sheet.  One can use a SUB but it would be easier just to use the same criteria that the custom format uses to count:

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E30,"Carry Over")
```

or to count where it is not red:

```
=COUNTIF(E2:E30,"<>Carry Over")
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Scott. I think your suggestion is great to count the # of items that have been Carried over (which I think I would need also). But, what if I want to get the total sum under column C ("Size") though for those "Carry Over" items?

Comment: Then use SUMIFS(): `=SUMIFS(C2:C30,E2:E30,"Carry Over")`

Comment: On second thoughts, I think I a "lengthy" workaround would be to get the values of corresponding C column cell value for every "Carry Over". Definitely not a one liner or an efficient way. Let me know if you have other thoughts.

Comment: Sounds like a plan :) Let me give it a whirl.

Comment: Scott - You da man :) Works like a charm. Thank you, kind sir!